# Change Cherrypy Port and restart web server

Tags: python, webserver, port, cherrypy

Is there a way in python to change the port that `cherrypy` is using and force the web server (not apache, cherrypy) to restart?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at [cherrypy.process.servers](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/process/servers.html). You can try something like this:

```
import cherrypy
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 8099})
cherrypy.engine.restart()
```

Comment: While I agree this should be the correct answer, I found that simply doing a config update and then calling restart on my server caused it to get 'stuck' with the messages: "Waiting for child threads to terminate..." and "Waiting for thread Thread-1.". Not sure why this would be.

Comment: restart()  appears to be not thread-safe, whereas stop() and start() are, at least in my environment where I run cp in a separate thread.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to replace the whole process (which is what `cherrypy.engine.restart()` does), you could do:

```
import cherrypy
cherrypy.engine.stop()
cherrypy.server.httpserver = None
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 8099})
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Setting httpserver to None is needed or the `cherrypy.engine.start()` call will just reuse the host/port it already has rather than picking up the changed configuration. I'm not sure if that is inappropriately taking advantage of an implementation detail, though.